# Why am I receiving invalid pointer error when running this code

Tags: c, pointers, free

I am receiving the following error when running this code.

Error in `main': free(): invalid pointer:

My idea is to use a pointer allocated through malloc. This is a sample code. 
Please let me know why I am receiving this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int c=10;
 int* ptr = NULL;
 ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

 if(ptr == NULL)
 {
   printf("Memory not allocated");
   exit(0);
 }

 ptr = &c;
 free(ptr);
 ptr=NULL;
}
```

Comment: Whats the `ptr = &c;` for?

Comment: `ptr = malloc(...)` followed by `ptr = &c` is similart to e.g. `int a; a = 10; a = 20;` and then wondering why `a` isn't equal to `10` anymore. Perhaps you're supposed to do `*ptr = c`?

Comment: And be careful about the difference between assignment using `=` and comparison for equality using `==`. You actually assign to `ptr` *three* times.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out == operator.
*ptr = c ended in segmentation fault.
I faced another issue, I removed all the unnecessary code to here.

Answer (score 2):

```
int c=10;
```

Variable **c** allocated on the stack.

```
ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Assign address of allocated memory on the heap to **ptr**

```
ptr = &c;
```

Assign address of **c** to **ptr**.

---

You have two problems in your code.

1. **Memory Leak**. You have lost address of allocated memory since you used reassign of **ptr**. In this case you don't have any other way to free memory allocated on the heap until program ends.
2. **You can't** free memory allocated on the stack with **free()** function. It's auto variables

---

So, If you were trying to assign the value of **c** to the allocated space:

```
*ptr = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I receiving an *invalid pointer* error?

Because you `free` a pointer that was not allocated with `malloc` (or `realloc`).

You have a **memory leak**, i.e. you lose a malloced pointer with `ptr = &c`, which assigns the address of `c` to `ptr`, losing the value returned by `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Well to do that you need to allocate for a pointer of pointer like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 int c=10;
 int** ptr = NULL;
 ptr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*));

 if(ptr == NULL)
 {
   printf("Memory not allocated");
   exit(0);
 }

 *ptr = &c;
 free(ptr);
 ptr=NULL;
}
```

the problem in your case that you are freeing a non dynamic allocated memory and that gives you an error, and even in other cases you should always keep the address of the allocated memory to free it when you no more need it for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 int *ptr1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
 int *ptr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
 *ptr1 = 5;
 *ptr2 = 10;
 // this is wrong because now there is no way to free
 // the address of the allocated memory to ptr1
 ptr1 = ptr2;
 free(ptr1);
 // this gives an error because ptr2 is already free
 free(ptr2);
}
```

**Conclusion:**
If you want to allocate to store a pointer, then you need to allocate for a pointer to pointer, so the pointer of the allocated memory stay so you can free that memory when you no longer need it